# django how to recover a single field from sqlite3

Tags: django, sqlite, django-queryset

i have this register on my db:

```
id nome  email            senha
2  teste teste@teste.com  1234
```

i'm trying to recover the 'senha' from the table, and i'm trying to use the rawqueryes

```
usuario = request.GET.get('enderecoEmail') -- teste@teste.com
senha2 = Usuario.objects.raw('select senha from projeto_usuario where email = %s',[usuario])
```

just for test i'm sending the argument to an html just to print

```
return render(request, 'projeto/teste.html',{'senha':senha2,'usuario':usuario})
```

however what i'm getting as result is

```
<RawQuerySet: select senha from projeto_usuario where email = teste@teste.com>
```

i wanna know how can i retrieve that field from the sqlite3, i have been reading the whole documentation, but i really don't know what i'm missing

Comment: You should do it like this instead of using raw sql. `senha = Usuario.objects.get(email=usario).senha`

Comment: it worked, however, there isn't any way to use sql statements? i will have to perform a lot of sql statements a lot more complex than this one

Comment: Yes, you can use sql statements, but it is generally more safe to use the ORM. If you use raw sql, and use users input for it, you can become vulnerable to SQL injection. Here's the django documentation on [making queries with the ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/queries/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 senha2 = Usuario.objects.raw('select senha from projeto_usuario where email = %s',[usuario])
```

replace above with below code

```
senha2= Usuario.objects.get(email=usuario)
senha2 = senha2.senha
```

Comment: it worked, however, there isn't any way to use sql statements? i will have to perform a lot of sql statements a lot more complex than this one

Comment: Yes, You can use sql statements in django but django have good orm that can perform mostly operations easily.